# Unity Runtime Surface Snapping (Like Shift+Cntrl in Editor)

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to allow the user of my VR game to move objects around using a pointer, then when holding down a button, snap to a grid and align to the highest surface, essentially replicating the Editor behavior or holding down shift+control and moving around a transform gizmo. (Try it, it's fun!)

I have the grid part down, but can't wrap my head around how to do the surface snapping.
Here is the code I have so far. I would appreciate any and all help!

```
 
// offsetPos is where the VR pointer is.
Vector3 offsetPos = pointer.objectControlPoint.transform.position + cursorOffset;
Vector3 newPos;
 
if (isSnapping) // Snap to ground code.
{
// I read previously to do this up then down thing, but It's not working as expected
    RaycastHit groundHit = new RaycastHit();
    if (Physics.Raycast(selectedObject.transform.position, Vector3.down, out groundHit))
    {
         RaycastHit objectHit = new RaycastHit();
         if (Physics.Raycast(groundHit.point, Vector3.up, out objectHit))
         {
                Vector3 snapDiff = groundHit.point - objectHit.point;
                snapYPos = snapDiff.y + (selectedObject.collider.bounds.extents.y);
          }
    }
      // worldGrid is a monoBehavior on another object, and gridCellSize is just a float
      float gridPosX = Mathf.Floor(offsetPos.x / worldGrid.gridCellSize) * worldGrid.gridCellSize;
      float gridPosZ = Mathf.Floor(offsetPos.z / worldGrid.gridCellSize) * worldGrid.gridCellSize;
      newPos = new Vector3(gridPosX, snapYPos, gridPosZ); // Sets the target position to the nearest grid cell, with a Y of the snap position.
}
else // If not in snap mode, set target position to just the VR cursor.
{
       newPos = new Vector3(offsetPos.x, offsetPos.y, offsetPos.z);
}
 
// I know lerp might not be the most efficient, but I like the smooth effect, and it looks good when snapping to the grid...
selectedObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(selectedObject.transform.position, newPos, movementLerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

The objects I need to be snapping all are different sizes and have their origins in different places, but all do have appropriate box colliders.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is each object fitting in one grid position or are they bigger than a single field?

Comment: @Zibelas It's not a typical building system, so I'm basically just moving the object to the center of the cell.  I'm not restricting users from placing objects anywhere on the grid, so it doesn't really matter how big/how many cells objects take up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question from a while ago, the solution was to use Raycasting to set the position on the ground like in the code above, but then using Transform.Translate to move the object upwards to compensate for the center point not always being at the bottom.
The challenge there is to find the amount to translate by.  This can be achieved by using Bounds.Extents.y.